# Initializing array of structures give error

Tags: c++, initializer-list, aggregate-initialization

I created this program but when compiling the following error message appears:

> function ‘void FillDatabase()’:
> main.cpp:59:4: error: could not convert '.... from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Schedule'

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Courses{
   long Course_ID;
    string name; 
    float Hours;
};

struct Students {
    long ID;
    string name; 
}; 

struct Instructors {
    long ID;
    string name; 
    string Email; 
    string Course; 
};

struct Schedule {
    Courses Course;
    Instructors instructor; 
    Students Student[10]; 
    std::string Hall_NO; 
    int Time=0;
};

void FillDatabase() 
{
   struct Schedule Sch[10]={
   
  {100,"C++ Basics",10.30f,10,"ahmed manna","gggg@gmail.com","c++",{ 10, "ali"},
        { 20, "Mohammed"},
        { 30, "Ahmad"},
        { 40, "Safaa"},
        { 50, "Marwa"},
        { 60, "Hind"},
        { 70, "Ibrahim"},
        { 80, "Ghada"},
        { 90, "Mahmud"},
        { 100, "Abdulsalam"},
        "holl_5",11}
       
   };
```

Where is the problem found? Or any other solutions?

Comment: @AHMEDMANNA to address some one use `@`, not `#` so that the corresponding person is notified

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do too much with one liners and then you're getting bogged down in incorrect placement of braces. A lot would be more apparent to you if you indent properly. It should look like this.

```
void FillDatabase()
{
    Schedule Sch[10] = {
        {
            { 100, "C++ Basics", 10.30f },
            { 10,"ahmed manna", "gggg@gmail.com", "c++" },
            {
                { 10, "ali" },
                { 20, "Mohammed" },
                { 30, "Ahmad" },
                { 40, "Safaa" },
                { 50, "Marwa" },
                { 60, "Hind" },
                { 70, "Ibrahim" },
                { 80, "Ghada" },
                { 90, "Mahmud" },
                { 100, "Abdulsalam" },
            },
            "holl_5",
            11
        },
    }; 
}
```

Thereafter you still have a problem that this type of [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) comes with many requirements one of which being [no default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) as with this line:

```
int Time=0;
```

You need to change that to

```
int Time;
```

I recommend you provide appropriate constructors to your various structs rather than relying on aggregate initialization. Otherwise, if you change the order to your members or add or delete members then your code will break. It's fragile as you have it.